# Cartesian product types

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to create the type `Cartesian` such that `Cartesian<'a' | 'b' | 'c'>` equals the type

```
'ab' | 'ba' | 'ac' | 'ca' | 'bc' | 'cb'
```

**Partial solution**: if we define `` type Cartesian<T extends string> = `${T}_${T}`; `` we also get `'aa'`, `'bb'`, and `'cc'`. Is there a way to remove those? Perhaps using `Exclude`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way you can create the required `Cartesian` type is by using the conditional and mapped types to exclude the undesired combinations. Something like:

```
type Cartesian<T extends string> = {
  [K1 in T]: {
    [K2 in T]: K1 extends K2 ? never : `${K1}${K2}`;
  }[T];
}[T];

type Result = Cartesian<'a' | 'b' | 'c'>;
// Result: 'ab' | 'ac' | 'ba' | 'bc' | 'ca' | 'cb'
```

[TS plaground](https://tsplay.dev/w21L9W)

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, here's another implementation of what you're calling `Cartesian` (although a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) wouldn't filter out repeated elements the way you want here):

```
type Cartesian<T extends string, U extends string = T> =
  T extends string ? `${T}${Exclude<U, T>}` : never

type Z = Cartesian<'a' | 'b' | 'c'>;
// type Z = "ab" | "ac" | "ba" | "bc" | "ca" | "cb"
```

It works by copying the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `T` to another type parameter `U` via a [default type argument](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults), and then produces a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) over the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) in `T`.  Thus the type acts on each member of `T` independently, but leaves `U` as the full union.  And then [the `Exclude` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) filters `U` to remove `T`, leading to the desired result.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgJ2BAzgSzgOwDwBUoQAeymAJilCsAmpgOYA0UAqgcRGRVTfVALxRcAPn4AoKILYlylarTpQA-FAAGAEgDeuAL6aAooQDGAGwCupCNmZNh2lVABcUTBABuEBKNGhIUAFr8sIjI6FjYAORw4VAAPlDhAEbRceGG4UIA3KIA9NlQPtABAgBEcAnFsVClhhVxxQlwtVUJNZXFho1thuVAA)